# Have gaps in a SVG path when there is no data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a realtime line graph in D3. My data is in the format of [[Date, value], [Date, value]. When I don't receive any data the value will be 0. I would like the line to break for these values so they are not plotted. I would then get gaps in my graph where I am missing data.

Anyone have any ideas how I would do this?

Comment: Have you written any code so far ?

Comment: I do, I have created a JS fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/srZwS/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this by creating several plots on a single set of axis.  Each continuos sets of data would be a separate plot.  Then just make sure you assign them all the same colour etc.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've tried that idea and I just think my data set is far too complicated for that. I've created a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srZwS/1 which details out the problem. I have no data for 18:00 - 09:00 and D3 just draws a straight line between the two. I would like not to have that join

Comment: The problem you are facing is that it really is not the correct type of graph to represent discontinuous data.  Using bar charts would be more appropriate (Appropriate for discontinuous data).  Using line graphs you will have to separate out your data to form multiple lines.

Comment: You are completely right, bar charts should be used. I just have a user who wants to use line charts.

Answer (score 11):

Try this. Variable my_dataset is array of objects with attributes {x,y}. "NaN: as y-value is skipped in visualization.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x( function( d, i) { return x( d.x); })
  .y( function( d) { return y( d.y); })
  .defined( function( d) { return !isNaN( d.y); })
  ;

my_visualization.append( "svg:path")
    .data( [ my_dataset])
    .attr( "d", line)
```