# add space/gap in a line in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I have a multiline chart similar to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955), where each line represent a particular year and the x-axis represents days`(e.g. Jan 1, Jan 2, ... Dec 31)` in that particular year.

some lines are for leap years and some are for non-leap years. For a non-leap year line, I want the date `Feb 29` to not display anything, i.e. a gap or a blank space in the line. Right now, my data set has `null` in the `Feb 29` object. So D3 considers that point as 0 and stretches it all the way to bottom(x-axis).

Is there any way to achieve a space in line? Or is there a workaround for this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: found this similar question, which has detailed info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141987/have-gaps-in-a-svg-path-when-there-is-no-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `line.defined`: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined

According to the API:

> The defined accessor can be used to define where the line is defined and undefined, which is typically useful in conjunction with missing data.

If your line should be undefined where the value is null or NaN, do this:

```
line.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.x); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that exactly.