# How to make a d3 multiple line chart with irregular data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very new to d3.js and I've been following many tutorials. Basically what I want to do is something that looks like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time). I'm getting there, but for some reason my chart turn out with some weird lines (notice Carol's path in jsbin)

here is jsbin of my code so far http://jsbin.com/poyinokobu/edit?html,output

I got to the conclusion that it was because I have irregular data on my JSON, but I do not know how to fix it. I've searched for similar problems but couldn't find any.

Please if someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it so much! This library is giving me so many headaches :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your dates in an ascending order:

```
cities.forEach(function(d){
    d.values.sort(function(a,b){
        return d3.ascending(a.date, b.date)
    })
});
```

Here is your JSBin: http://jsbin.com/jiqayicuji/1/edit

Comment: Thank you! Do you by any chance know how can I make so that the days where there is no data (i.e. say on fri 07 only three people have values, and the rest dont have data on that day) they all still appear and people with no values appear as "zero"

Comment: Yes, just use `line.defined`. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846788/add-space-gap-in-a-line-in-d3/37847137#37847137  And also this one, with the demo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748271/d3-linearly-interpolate-only-close-enough-points/39750744#39750744